# How to sort javascript object collection by boolean string field

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort the collection like:

1) Only having "shared==true" column result should be appear first and all other should be after words.
tried with below approach but it does not work and show random.

```js
var cmp= function (a, b) {  
            
            if (a.shared == 'true' && b.shared != 'true') return -1;
            if (a.shared != 'true' && b.shared == 'true') return 0;
            return 1;
        }
        
var data= [{'id':1, 'name':'addd', 'shared':'true'},{'id':2, 'name':'addd1', 'shared':'false'},{'id':3, 'name':'addd2', 'shared':'true'}]
data.sort(cmp);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: That's no Boolean; that's a string...

Comment: @HereticMonkey imposter!

Comment: edited title. its string value but true or false and need sorting by that.

Comment: `data.sort((a,b) => (b.shared == 'true') - (a.shared == 'true'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there. In your second `if`, you want to return 1. If both are true, you want to return 0. So you last return should be `return 0`.

```js
var cmp = function(a, b) {
  if (a.shared == 'true' && b.shared != 'true') return -1;
  if (a.shared != 'true' && b.shared == 'true') return 1;
  return 0;
}

var data = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'addd',
  'shared': 'true'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'addd1',
  'shared': 'false'
}, {
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'addd2',
  'shared': 'true'
}]
data.sort(cmp);
console.log(data);
```

From the [description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description):

```
if (a is greater than b by the ordering criterion) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with filter and concat

```js
var data = [{
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'addd',
  'shared': 'true'
}, {
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'addd1',
  'shared': 'false'
}, {
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'addd2',
  'shared': 'true'
}]


const sorted = data.filter(x => x.shared === 'true').concat(data.filter(x => x.shared !== 'true'));
console.log(sorted);
```